# Storing child class as variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I have a statement like this.

```js
let Polygon = class{
  constructor(){
    //stuff
  }
  
  draw(){
    //more stuff
  }
}
```

I want to extend this class as such:

```js
class Board extends Polygon{
  constructor(){
    //stuff
  }
}
```

But I also want to store it as a variable like Polygon. Using this:

```js
let Board = class extends Polygon{

}
```

does not work. How can I store it like I did with Polygon?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your last snippet works without a problem for me (Chrome/Mac 76).

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way rather than `class Board extends Polygon { }`? You *can*, but I'm curious why you want to if you're going to use `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine (but keep reading):

```js
let Polygon = class{
  constructor(){
    //stuff
  }
  
  draw(){
    //more stuff
  }
};

let Board = class extends Polygon {

};

console.log(typeof Board);
```

...but note that

```
let Board = class extends Polygon {

};
```

and

```
class Board extends Polygon {

}
```

do **exactly** the same thing. They both:

- Create a mutable variable called `Board` in the current execution context using modern identifier scoping and semantics (e.g., with the Temporal Dead Zone, etc.) upon entry to the scope in which the above occurs. `let`, `const`, and `class` all use modern identifier semantics. (`var` uses the legacy scoping and semantics.)
- Initialize that variable with the constructor created by the `class` constructor to `Board`, when that statement/declaration is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code.

(In contrast, `const Board = class extends Polygon { };` makes the identifier binding immutable.)